# Removing subview hierarchy from root view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, subviews

In the root view controller I add a subview:

```
d4sViewController = [[D4sViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"D4sViewController" bundle:nil];

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Move your sub-view off the screen.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [self.view addSubview:d4sViewController.view];

        CGRect rect = d4sViewController.view.frame;
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(320, 0);
        rect.origin = origin;
        d4sViewController.view.frame = rect;

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Use a transform to slide it on.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        d4sViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

IN `D4sViewController` I add 2 subviews:

```
d4sMainList1ViewController = [[D4sMainList1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"D4sMainList1ViewController" bundle:nil];


        // Move your sub-view off the screen.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [self.view addSubview:d4sMainList1ViewController.view];
```

From this subview, `d4sMainList1ViewController`, I want to give a logout functionality and go back to root view controller by removing all subview.

```
-(IBAction)buttonLogoutClicked:(id)sender
{
 //logout code i need to implement  
}
```

`Rootview => d4sViewController => d4sMainList1ViewController` (from here i need to remove all subviews of root and go back to displaying just the root view.)

Answer (score 2):

To remove any subview have the send the subview the `removeFromSuperView` message. See the UIView docs for details.

However, it looks like your stacking views when you don't need to. On a mobile screen a big pile of views is unusable. Look into using UINavigationController to managed a hierarchy of views/viewControllers for you.